# Can not access response.body inside after filter block in Sinatra 1.0

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm struggling with a strange issue. According to http://github.com/sinatra/sinatra (secion Filters) a response object is available in after filter blocks in Sinatra 1.0. However the response.status is correctly accessible, I can not see non-empty response.body from my routes inside after filter.

I have this rackup file:

*config.ru*

```
require 'app'
run TestApp
```

Then Sinatra 1.0.b gem installed using:

```
gem install --pre sinatra
```

And this is my tiny app with a single route:

*app.rb*

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra/base'

class TestApp < Sinatra::Base

  set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)

  get '/test' do
    'Some response'
  end

  after do
    halt 500 if response.empty? # used 500 just for illustation
  end

end
```

And now, I would like to access the response inside the after filter. When I run this app and access **/test** URL, I got a **500** response as if the response is empty, but the response clearly is 'Some response'.

Along with my request to /test, a separate request to /favicon.ico is issued by the browser and that returns **404** as there is no route nor a static file. But I would expect the **500** status to be returned as the response should be empty.

In console, I can see that within the after filter, the response to /favicon.ico is something like 'Not found' and response to /test really is empty even though there is response returned by the route.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The response.body is set Sinatra::Base#invoke, which wraps around Sinatra::Base#dispatch!, which in turn calls the filters. However, #invoke sets the response body after dispatch! is done, therefore the body is not yet set. What you want to do is probably better solved with a rack middleware.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I was looking at the *after* filter as a kind of *ensure* block for all routes. However I still think that when the *response* object is available in after block and has a response.status set (especially 200), it should contain the body and should not be empty. Or am I so mistaken?

Comment: what about the response status and all that? For instance, I'd like to run a certain after filter only when the response is successful. However, in my after filter, the status is always 200, EVEN when i call halt with 404 in a before filter of the same route. If I can't do that, I fail to see what the after filters are for.

Comment: ChuckE: What version of Sinatra are you running? Could you open an issue?